# How can I clear space on my Raspberry Pi?

Tags: pi-2

I am not able to get enough space on my Pi — I am only getting 1.3GB free even after deleting all the contents which have a total of 8GB. How can I make more space on my Pi?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure your device has file system over entire sd card with `raspi-config` command. Also, try commands such as `sudo apt-get autoremove` and `sudo apt-get clean` in order to remove unnecessary dependencies and cache. Also, if you're using 8 GB card I'd suggest using Lite version of Raspbian, since this is a very small ammount.

Comment: of course, the LITE version means no GUI

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to pull out the sd card from the device an rewrite ist using the instruction from

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/installation/installing-images/README.md

Comment: in other words, this will reinitialise the SD card, overwriting it, without saving anything on it you may deem important

Answer (score 2):

Buy a new SDCard that's 16GB or 32GB and never worry about available space again.

Also ditch NOOBS, it wastes 1.3GB of space to keep the recovery system you'll never use. If you need NOOBS use NOOBS Lite or PINN.

Answer (score 1):

Use `bleachbit`, it frees GB's of space at times.
To install it:

```bsh
sudo apt update
sudo apt install bleachbit -y
```

Run it from the menu shortcut.